# Intercepting didAddSubview

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, overriding, subclass

I hope this is a simple question. I need to intercept `didAddSubview`, but will I need to subclass the `UIView` in order to override that method?

The `UIView` that I want to override is the `UIViewController`'s `view` property, so I just want to know how to go about working with this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Apple [`UIView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html) documentation (see *Methods to Override*):

> When subclassing UIView, there are only a handful of methods you
>   should override and many methods that you might override depending on
>   your needs. Because UIView is a highly configurable class, there are
>   also many ways to implement sophisticated view behaviors without
>   overriding custom methods, which are discussed in the Alternatives to
>   Subclassing section. **In the meantime, the following list includes
>   the methods you might consider overriding in your UIView subclasses**:
>
> - ...
> - `didAddSubview:`, `willRemoveSubview:` - Implement these methods as needed to track the  additions and removals of subviews.
> - ...

So, create your `UIView` subclass and override the method. Then, say to your `UIViewController` that its `view` will be the one you have subclassed. To achieve this there are a couple of ways:

- by Xib
- implementing `loadView` method and set the `view` property to be your custom view
- redifining the `view` property in `viewDidLoad`

Hope that helps.

Comment: So I would have to subclass the UINavigationController's view. Thats what I was thinking, but I wasn't sure. I hope you don't mind, but I may wait for another answer to just see if there's anything else.

Comment: I have a couple questions about this forum. When you edited my question, how did you change my coding references into code bound text? Did you highlight it and select the code block option? Also, to reply to someone, do you just simply write out their name with an '@' in front of it?

Comment: @RileyE First question: Yes. Use *CTRL + K* (Windows) or *CMD + K* (Mac) to format code. Second question: Yes, use *@* to notify someone else in comments. For further info see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help