# Program crash when override addSubview method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a customer UIView "CustomerUIView", and the CustomerUIView holds an instance of the UIView named "contentView". When an other view added as a subview of the instance of CustomerUIView, I want the view added as the subview of "contentView", so I override the addSubView method in CustomerUIView as below :

```
- (void)addSubview:(UIView *)view
{
    [contentView addSubview:view];
}
```

But when I ran the program, it crashed somehow. So does that mean it is not correct to override the addSubview method?

As in my old code, many places has used the addSubview method, and that is the reason why I want to override that method instead of writing another method to use. Some advise?

Comment: what does the exception say? I occasionally overwrite `addSubview` and have no problem with doing so.

Comment: It might be easier for the program to receive an alert when the subview is added instead, then you can run whatever code you need to then. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364646/intercepting-didaddsubview

Alternatively, you could call try calling the super version of the method, and then running your own code, like:
`- (void)addSubview:(UIView *)view
{
    [super addSubview:view];
    [view removeFromSuperview];
    [contentView addSubview:view];
}`

Comment: Sorry for the formatting, will put it in an answer instead

Answer (score 2):

It might be easier for the program to receive an alert when the subview is added instead, then you can run whatever code you need to then. See [stackoverflow.com/questions/11364646/intercepting-didaddsubview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364646/intercepting-didaddsubview)

Alternatively, you could call try calling the super version of the method, and then running your own code, like:

```
- (void)addSubview:(UIView *)view { 
    [super addSubview:view]; 
    [view removeFromSuperview]; 
    [contentView addSubview:view]; 
}
```